# changing the Angular-material sidenav with a Polymer drawer

Tags: html, polymer, angular-material

I just started with material design and i wanted to use angular material but with some features and elements that polymer have and angular don't. So i tried changing the sidenav in the starter pack with the drawer panel and the header panel like this:

Before:

```
<md-sidenav class="site-sidenav md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')">
    <md-toolbar class="md-whiteframe-z1">
      <h1>Users</h1>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-list>
      <md-list-item ng-repeat="it in ul.users">
          <md-button ng-click="ul.selectUser(it)" ng-class="{'selected' : it === ul.selected }">
            <md-icon md-svg-icon="{{it.avatar}}" class="avatar"></md-icon>
            {{it.name}}
          </md-button>
      </md-list-item>
    </md-list>
</md-sidenav>
```

After:

```
<paper-drawer-panel responsive-width="4000px">
      <paper-header-panel class="waterfall tbackground" drawer>
        <paper-toolbar class="specialToolbar">
            <div class="paper-font-title">Content</div>
          </paper-toolbar>
    <md-list>
      <md-list-item ng-repeat="it in ul.users">
          <md-button ng-click="ul.selectUser(it)" ng-class="{'selected' : it === ul.selected }">
            <md-icon md-svg-icon="{{it.avatar}}" class="avatar"></md-icon>
            {{it.name}}
          </md-button>
      </md-list-item>
    </md-list>
</paper-header-panel>
```

And the whole nav dissapeared!...i have read that it is possible to use both , polymer and angular, simultaneously but i don't know how

 i imported everything btw...

Comment: Acctually I did that change here: https://github.com/odahcam/polyng . It worked very well, except of AOT compilation which produced a bloated bundle size, so I couldn't use it in production.

Answer (score 0):

Polymer and Angular can be used together.

The `responsive-width` set on it is quite a large value means that it's probably being changed to narrow layout. With a value of 4000px that means that if your display is smaller than that, the drawer will be forced off screen.

You can still access it if you tap and drag the side of the screen. Or you can put some element (eg. a button) with a `paper-drawer-toggle`attribute to show it. Otherwise, change the `responsive-width` to a more moderate value (the default is 640px).